# Checking from method for what method called it

Tags: java

Say, I have some Java code

```
public static void method1(){
...//method body
method2();
}
public static void method2(){
...//method body
}
```

I want method2 to be able to know, as a String, what method called it. For example, in this case, if method1 were run, calling method2, method2  could print out that it was called from method1.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you want do to this, what are you trying to do?

Comment: Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace().

Answer (score 4):

```
StackTraceElement[] ste = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();
```

> The last element of the array represents the bottom of the stack, which is the least recent method invocation in the sequence.

Answer (score 0):

```
StackTraceElement[] stackElements = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();
System.out.println(stackElements[1].getMethodName());
```

You might have to check which index you want.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like that:

```
public class App
{   
    static public void main(String[] args) {
        secondMethod();
    }   

    public static void secondMethod() {
        StackTraceElement[] ste = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();
        System.out.println(ste[ste.length-1]);          
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public class TestClass {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        m1();
    }

    static void m1() {
        m2();
    }

    static void m2() {
        StackTraceElement[] stackTrace = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();
        System.out.println(stackTrace[2].getMethodName());
    }
}
```